# How can I remove words with more vowels then consonants using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am working on an app that removes from the text words which contain more vowels than consonants. For example:

```
 StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("I quite hate regular expressions");
```

I have to write code that will return `text` without the words "quite" and "I", because these words contain more vowels than consonants. Also it should work with other text samples.

I am quite bad at Java regular expressions, so I hope you guys will help me.   I have tried

```
public String removeWordsWithMoreVowels(final StringBuilder text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("regular expression goes here");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
    return matcher.replaceAll("");
}
```

How can I achieve that? All hints and advice are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no regular expression for that. If you want I can prove that to you.

Comment: I know that this task is not just about regular expression, but it should be used here.

Comment: In addition to "quite", "I" should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cannot really be done with regex. The problem is that **v<sup>n</sup>c<sup>n</sup>** is not suited for such stateless, context free grammar as in regex. Using the regex with with a lambda,
one can use a bit of code.

```
public String removeWordsWithMoreVowels(final StringBuilder text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b[a-z]+\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.replaceAll(mr -> {
        int vowels = mr.group().replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
        return vowels > mr.group().length() - vowels ? "" : mr.group();
    });
}
```

The above is a slight simplification as it does not deal with removing whitespace by the deletion.

- `(?i)` case insensitive
- `[^aeiou]` - not a vowel; consonant (about `y`: maybe one should remove them first)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution.  It does use a single regular expression for the vowels.

- remove all the vowels from the word. Let the new Length be `NC` for number of consonants.
- subtract `NC` from the orig word length.  That is the number of vowels, `VC`
- If `VC <= NC`, keep the word.  Note that this keeps words where the number of vowels equal the number of consonants.

```
    String[] words = { "radar", "hello", "saygoodbyeeee","coolbeans" };
// or
    String[] words = "I quite hate regular expressions".split("\\s+");
```

Then use this

```
        List<String> keep = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : words) {
           int nocons = word.replaceAll("(?i:[aeiou])","").length();
           if (word.length()-nocons <= nocons) {
               keep.add(word);
           }
        }

        System.out.println(keep);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in a general case: finite-state machines, which regexes are, cannot count `n` matches to a possibly infinite limit.

You can do what you want up to a finite number of consonants `c` and a finite number of vowels `v`, but you cannot create a general regex to express all matches of `c < v` such that `c -> infinity` and `v -> infinity`.

Your problem can be expressed by a context-sensitive matcher (which is a **linear-bounded automata**).

You'd best be served by manually counting the number of vowels vs. consonants per word and then using a comparison to filter out the words -- use a lambda expression.